# How to add splash art to an android notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I came across this notification while doing some research and it has me wondering... how do you include this splash art in the notification list on Android?

I have not seen an Android app do this before. Checking Google's documentation (https://developer.android.com/preview/notifications.html), I don't see it mentioned.

Any thoughts or ideas on how this is accomplished?

http://postimg.org/image/mtan1vcfn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom notification layout via `RemoteViews`. Have a [look at the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification).

You first create a `RemoteViews` with your custom layout. This is the normal XML file you are used to. Then call the [`Notification.Builder.setContent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContent(android.widget.RemoteViews)) and pass in your `RemoteViews`.

And, dont forget to set the small icon for your notification or else it just wont display.